# Tensorflow Input Feeding Error when moving from Python 2 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I had a Tensorflow code that worked well with python 2. I need to switch to Python 3. besides, minor changes, this is the big error I am getting. Something is causing input feeding error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 530, in <module>
    train(config)
  File "main.py", line 337, in train
    loss,train_op = trainer.step(sess,batch)
  File "trainer.py", line 33, in step
    loss, train_op = sess.run([self.loss,self.train_op],feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "anaconda2/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "anaconda2/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1116, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'simple_lstm/pre_emb_mat:0', which has shape '(?, 100)'
```

How could I resolve it?

Comment: How about changing tensor shape with np.reshape function?